What is the meaning of these Greek words ἵπποπείρην and ἐπεμβάτην?
Recently I have come across this short poem of Anacreon, which I give below in its totality for the sake of context:

Πῶλε Θρῃκίη, τί δή με
λοξὸν ὄμμασι βλέπουσα
νηλεῶς φεύγεις; δοκεῖς δέ
μ’ οὐδὲν εἰδέναι σοφόν;
ἴσθι τοι, καλῶς μὲν ἄν τοι
τὸv χαλινὸν ἐμβάλοιμι,
ἡνίας δ᾽ ἔχων στρέφοιμί
σ΄ἀμφὶ τέρματα δρόμου᾽
νῦν δὲ λειμῶνάς τε βόσκεαι
κοῦφά τε σκιρτῶσα παίζεις,
δεξιὸν γὰρ ἱπποπείρην
οὐκ ἔχεις ἐπεμβάτην.

Everything in this composition is clear to me, except for two words in the final lines: ἵπποπείρην and ἐπεμβάτην.
I've searched for the meaning of both in a dictionary, unsuccessfully. I've tried to use Wiktionary as well, but again without results. Can anyone figure out what is the meaning of these words?
Also, I'm not very sure about what person, time, and voice the verb βόσκεαι has (9th line).

An ἐπεμβάτης is a "horse-rider," related to ἐπεμβαίνω, "to step upon, to mount."
So δεξιὸν οὐκ ἔχεις ἐπεμβάτην means "you do not have a skillful horse-rider." The noun is masculine, and is modified by δεξιὸν, "skillful."
While ἱπποπείρης is more unusual, and you'll need the LSJ Supplement (which I don't think is online) to see its meaning, but you can approximate its meaning by breaking it into its component parts, ἵππος ("horse") and πεῖρα ("attempt" or "experience"). So, "experienced in horses" is a natural conclusion (and what the LSJ Supplement also has).
Putting that together you get:

For you do not have a skillful horse-rider (δεξιὸν ἐπεμβάτην) experienced in horses (ἱπποπείρην).

For your addendum, βόσκεαι here is 2nd person singular present middle indicative, "now you feed."

Oh... regarding the addendum, should I visualize an old σ between the vowels ε and α? I missed it because the middle voice was not evident to me...

@IesusHominumSalvator It's the uncontracted form. See this summary on Wiktionary: "-(σ)οι is attested in Arcadian κεῖοι (with elision of intervocalic -σ-; Attic κεῖσαι). -(σ)η in Boeotian, -(σ)ει in Thessalian by regular sound change. -(σ)αι in all other dialects. In Attic thematic -εαι contracted to -ῃ, and after 400 BC this shortened to -ει."
